# Creating list of names from a text file through indexing (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am building an app for selecting 11 players from Team A and Team B

I am using below logic to select players from Team A and Team B:-

```js
{
  name: 'Logic 7',
  teamAIndices: [0, 3, 4, 9, 10],
  teamBIndices: [0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 10],
  captainIndex: [10], // 1st player from Team A
  viceCaptainIndex: [6], // 3rd player from Team A
},
```

But whenever i am selecting teamBIndices(TeamB) last player as 10th (means 11th player) and captainIndex (Means captain of the team) as 10th player (means 11th player of the created team), it is giving me only 10 player. After logging it is found that teamBIndices(TeamB) last player as 10th (means 11th player) is not being selected, but i don't know why.

Apart from this if i am using below logic,  it is creating complete 11 players team:-

```js
{
  name: 'Logic 6',
  teamAIndices: [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10],
  teamBIndices: [0, 3, 4, 6, 10],
  captainIndex: [6], // 1st player from Team A
  viceCaptainIndex: [8], // 3rd player from Team A
},
```

I need to select 11 players for a team. I am working on javascript.

I am creating team like this:-

```js
function createTeam(teamA, teamB, config) {
  const selectedPlayers = [
    ...config.teamAIndices.map((index) => teamA[index]),
    ...config.teamBIndices.map((index) => teamB[index]),
  ];

  const captainIndex = config.captainIndex;
  const viceCaptainIndex = config.viceCaptainIndex;

  // Assign Captain and Vice Captain without adding line breaks
  selectedPlayers[captainIndex] += ' (C)';
  selectedPlayers[viceCaptainIndex] += ' (VC)';
  return selectedPlayers; // Return the array of players
}
```

Comment: What do teamA, teamB and config look like

Comment: `selectedPlayers[captainIndex]` where `captainIndex = [10]` does not make sense. The captain index should be a single integer.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I don't seem to have a problem with the first logic. Please post a wrong output based on what you wrote, otherwise it's hard to compare. Did you make sure both your `teamA` and `teamB` have at least 11 elements?

Comment: @atteggiani I have 11 players in each team a and team b, and the output is as under:-

`Team 7 (Logic 7)
Player1
Player2 
Player3
Player4
Player5
Player6
Player7 (WK) (VC)
Player8
Player9
Player10 (C)
`

Comment: please, select answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You should call:

```
selectedPlayers[captainIndex[0]]
```

and

```
selectedPlayers[viceCaptainIndex[0]]
```

or reset your config to:

```
captainIndex: 6, // 1st player from Team A
viceCaptainIndex: 8, // 3rd player from Team A
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code is ok, the problem with the function i use to remove (C) or (VC) that is placed under the player name in a separate line during creation of team. Below is the code which is deleting the line which contains (C) and (VC) so, if am choosing captainindex(10) it was making Captain to 11th player which was deleted by the function below and moving that (C) to the 10th player:-

```
const modifiedFormattedTeam = formattedTeam.join('\n')
      .replace(/\r?\n?.*\(C\).*$/gm, ' (C)')
      .replace(/\r?\n?.*\(VC\).*$/gm, ' (VC)');
```